# Perhaps a simple question about a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Assume $a_n$ is a monotonic increasing sequence that tends to $\infty$, and assume that $(a_{n+1}/a_n)$ tends to 1.
Now, let $f:R\to R$ be a continuous function such that for all $x>0$ we have $f(a_nx)$ tends to $0$ as $n$ increases. Is it necessarily true that $f(x)$ tends to $0$ at $\infty$?

Comment: Just a tip, to type $a_{n+1}$, type "a_{n+1}"

Comment: Thank you! couldn't get that to work.

Comment: I see that this question has already been asked, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116656/forall-x0-lim-n-to-inftyfa-nx-0-then-lim-x-to-inftyfx-0.